# Commerce - Discount on three or more products in order

Tags: 7, commerce

I am moving my site from Ubercart to Commerce and would like to replicate a discount that I have set up in Ubercart.
I have an Ubercart coupon that automatically adjusts the price for a product if there are three or more applicable products in the order.
I have spent all day looking at [Commerce Coupons](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon) and [Commerce Discounts](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) but have not found a way to do this yet
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at these modules that provide some extra conditions:

- [Commerce Discount Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount_extra) provides a "Order has product(s) and quantity" condition that might match what you want.
- [Commerce Discount Product Quantity](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount_product_category) allows you to set up a discount based on the number of products in an order that belong to a category (taxonomy).

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I am still having trouble working our how to do this. If i want to do this using taxonomy which term on the product has to have the appropriate taxonomy? Also I want it to apply the discount if the order has any three of the products with that taxonomy. Not sure how I go about this??

Comment: There is a module called commerce discount taxonomy that might work as well.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking to do this I achieved it using Commerce Discount Product Category and Commerce Rules Extra.
I set up a product category and tagged the products I wanted to include in the discount. Created a discount for that product category and then edited the rule to in include Total quantity of selected product comparison